# Redireccionar una pagina web

Tags: javascript, html5, servidor

Traté de redireccionar mi pagina montada en servidor de

> `192.168.xxx.xxx`

a

> `192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/web/`

usando

```js
window.location
window.location.href
document.location
document.location.href
windows.location.replace()
```

todas me dan el mismo resultado

> `192.168.xxx.xxx/192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/web/`

¿alguna idea o forma de hacerlo?

**html**

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=http://192.168.XXX.XXX:8080/web/'>
</head>
<body>
<!--
<script>
 function red(){
      window.location.replace("http://192.168.XXX.XXX:8080/web/");
}

red();

</script>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: quieres que ese comportamiento se de desde un botón o que cuando el usuario escriba la URL se rediriga a la nueva URL?

Comment: 192.168.xxx.xxx  -->  sitio con pagina en blanco  ; 192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/web/   --->sitio a mostrar   ;  seria cuando el usuario escriba la URL se rediriga a la nueva URL

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner http:// delante de la IP al redireccionar?

Comment: Si quieres que siempre se redireccione, no lo hagas con JavaScript; usa las redirecciones del servidor web o del lenguaje del lado del servidor para ello. El método que estás usando no es recomendable porque es más lento, requiere más ancho de banda y puede dar una mala experiencia de usuario.

Comment: @user75463 has podido solucionarlo con la respuesta propuesta?

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.replace(...)` es mejor que usar `window.location.href`, porque `replace ()` no mantiene la página de origen en el historial de la sesión, lo que significa que el usuario no se quedará atrapado en un back-end interminable.

> Si quieres simular un link, usa **`location.href`**
>
> Si quieres simular un HTTP redirect, usa **`location.replace`**

Por ejemplo:

```
// comportamiento similar HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// comportamiento similar al presionar en un link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

En tu caso, puedes usar ambos pero te recomiendo el `window.location.href` ya que será un redireccionamiento automático. También deberías poner el http:// delante, para que se interprete como tal.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)